# Specifically Iterating through a file in perl

Tags: perl

So, I have this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Math::Vector::Real;
use constant DEG_PER_RAD => 45 / atan2(1, 1);

my ( $source, $out ) = qw/ OUT4 OUTABA12 /;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $source or die qq{Unable to open "$source" for input: $!\n};
open my $out_fh, '>', $out    or die qq{Unable to open "$out" for output: $!\n};


my @data;
push @data, V(split) while <$in_fh>;
my @aoa;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#data ) {
    for my $j ( 0 .. $#data ) {
        my $val1 = $data[$i];
        my $val2 = $data[$j];

        if ($val1 != $val2) {

            my $math = sqrt(($val1->[0] - $val2->[0])**2 +
                ($val1->[1] - $val2->[1])**2 +
                ($val1->[2] - $val2->[2])**2);

                if ($math < 2.2) {
                print "@$val1 @$val2 $math\n";
                    push @aoa, [@$val1, @$val2, $math];
                    }
        }
    }
}

for my $k ( 0 .. $#aoa-1 ) {

        my $aoadata1 = $aoa[$k];
        my $aoadata2 = $aoa[$k+1];

        my $vect1 = [ @{ $aoa[$k] }[0..2] ];
        my $vect2 = [ @{ $aoa[$k+1] }[0..2] ];
        my $vect3 = [ @{ $aoa[$k] }[3..5] ];
        my $vect4 = [ @{ $aoa[$k+1] }[3..5] ];
        my $math1 = [ @{ $aoa[$k] }[6] ];
        my $math2 = [ @{ $aoa[$k+1] }[6] ];

        my @matha = @$math1;
        my @mathb = @$math2;
        my @vecta = @$vect1;
        my @vectb = @$vect2;
        my @vectc = @$vect3;
        my @vectd = @$vect4;

            if ( @vecta != @vectb ) {

                print "1\n";

                }
}
```

Which runs on a test file like so:

```
 18.474525 20.161419 20.33903
 21.999333 20.220667 19.786734
 18.333228 21.649157 21.125111
 20.371077 19.675844 19.77649
 17.04323 19.3106 20.148842
 22.941106 19.105412 19.069893
```

and it calculates the distance between each point and every other point, and if it's below a threshold push it to an array for later. (For testing purposes, I also have it printing it. )

What I've been stuck on is the bottom half - I'm trying to eventually get to the point where the bottom half of the script script will iterate between rows like so:

If the first triple set of values on row 1 is not identical to the first set of triple values on row two, print 180, but only if this is the only instance of this line. If there is ever a point where row one's values were equal to row two's, do not print 180 whatsoever.

I cannot, for the life of me, get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that you haven't had any solutions because your description is very hard to understand. I can't see what you mean by *“the first triple set of values”* on a row, as each row contains only three values. I also don't get *“If there is ever a point where row one's values were equal to row two's”*, as row one and row two of the file are fixed and don't vary depending which point is being processed. I think you should show an example of what you are talking about, and show the output you want for data that has multiple identical points, and for data that is wholly unique

Comment: You're loading the `Math::Vector::Real` module but you don't use its capabilities. For instance, if you have two vectors `$v1` and `$v2` that are generated by `V(split)` as in your program, then the delta vector is just `$v1 - $v2`, and you can use `abs` to get the magnitude of the delta so you can write `my $math = abs($val1 - $val2)` instead of all that Pythagoras arithmetic. Also, the two vectors are identical if `$math == 0`

Comment: @Borodin , gotcha, thanks. Ive reposted/updated the question. I appreciate the feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not following. You talk about *"the first triple set of values on row 1"* but row 1 -- like all the rows -- has only one set of coordinates so I don't understand you using "first". Really, an example would help enormously

Comment: @Borodin on the new question i posted? Theres a new post entirely, i was going to delete this one but i wanted you to see the comment first. There is an example on the new one. Sorry if I'm being confusing.

Comment: Ah okay I misunderstood, and thought you meant you had updated *this* question. You should have posted [a link to your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630561/data-processing-by-iterating-through-an-array-in-perl) to save people having to search your profile to find your most recent output

Comment: @Borodin you have a fair point. Ill keep that in mind for next time. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct

I've used the facilities of the [`Math::Vector::Real`](http://metacpan.org/module/Math::Vector::Real) module as I described in a comment

- I leave the vectors as objects and avoid accessing their their contents directly
- I calculate the distance between `$vec1` and `$vec2` as `abs($vec1 - $vec2`
- I use the class's *stringify* ability to display it instead of extracting the individual values in my code

I have also changed the intermediate data format. The distance is no longer kept because it's not necessary, and the array `@groups` now contains an array for each group of vector pairs that have a common first vector. Each group is of the form

```
[ $vec1, $vec2, $vec2, $vec2, ... ]
```

and I use the `first` function from [`List::Util`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::Util) to find the group that each new vector pair belongs in. If an existing group is found with a matching first value then the second vector is just pushed onto the end of the group; otherwise a new group is created that looks like `[ $vec1, $vec2 ]`

Once the `@groups` array is built, it is processed again to generate the output

- If there are only two values in the group then they are `$vec1` and `$vec2` of a unique point. `$vec1` is printed with `180`
- If there are more than two elements then a line of output is generated for every pair of `$vec2` values, each containing the value `$vec1` together with the angle between the two `$vec2` vectors in the pair

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Vector::Real qw/ V /;
use List::Util qw / first /;

use constant DEG_PER_RAD => 45 / atan2(1, 1);

my ( $source, $out ) = qw/ OUT4 OUTABA12 /;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $source or die qq{Unable to open "$source" for input: $!\n};

my @data = map V(split), <$in_fh>;

my @groups;

for my $vec1 ( @data ) {

    for my $vec2 ( @data ) {

        next if abs($vec1 - $vec2) > 2.2 or $vec1 == $vec2;

        my $group = first { $_->[0] == $vec1 } @groups;

        if ( $group ) {
            push @$group, $vec2;
        }
        else {
            push @groups, [ $vec1, $vec2 ];
        }
    }
}

open my $out_fh, '>', $out or die qq{Unable to open "$out" for output: $!\n};
select $out_fh;

for my $group ( @groups ) {

    my ($vec1, @vec2) = @$group;

    if ( @vec2 == 1 ) {
        print "$vec1 180\n";
        next;
    }

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#vec2-1 ) {
        for my $j ( $i+1 .. $#vec2 ) {
            my ($vec2a, $vec2b) = @vec2[$i, $j];
            my $angle = atan2( $vec2a, $vec2b ) * DEG_PER_RAD;
            print "$vec1 $angle\n";
        }
    }

}
```

#### output

```
{18.474525, 20.161419, 20.33903} 4.96831567625921
{18.474525, 20.161419, 20.33903} 1.65052300046634
{18.474525, 20.161419, 20.33903} 4.80888617553369
{21.999333, 20.220667, 19.786734} 4.22499387836286
{18.333228, 21.649157, 21.125111} 180
{20.371077, 19.675844, 19.77649} 5.09280172684743
{17.04323, 19.3106, 20.148842} 180
{22.941106, 19.105412, 19.069893} 180
```

Comment: It looks like the end angles may be in radians? They should be higher. I may just have to recheck my data though. But I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be that low.  I very well could be wrong.